# How to remove stray â\302â in C++ ?

Tags: c++, c, linux, vi

How to remove stray â\302â  in C++ ?

I do not want to remove them one by one by hitting delet button.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't. You use something such as libiconv or ICU to convert the [UTF-8 text](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) to a charset you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

Since the post by OP currently is tagged with [vi](/questions/tagged/vi) I assume that OP is looking for a way to delete all characters (with a octal value of 302<sub>8</sub>) from within this editor.

---

```
:%s/\%o302//g
```

The above command will search the whole file for the octal value `\302` and replace every instance with an empty string.